# Extend struts data-sources, and change it to jndi

Tags: java, hibernate, struts, jndi

I have a api, which using below xml to do a connection, they provide us a xml as below:

> struts-config.xml

```
    <data-source type="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <set-property property="defaultAutoCommit"          value="false"/>
        <set-property property="defaultReadOnly"            value="false"/>
        <set-property property="driverClassName"            value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
        <set-property property="maxActive"                  value="60"/>
        <set-property property="maxIdle"                    value="5"/>
        <set-property property="maxWait"                    value="5000"/>
        <set-property property="poolPreparedStatements"     value="false"/>
        <set-property property="maxOpenPreparedStatements"  value="500"/>
        <set-property property="password"                   value="password"/>
        <set-property property="url"                        value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:abcd"/>
        <set-property property="username"                   value="username"/>
        <set-property property="logAbandoned"               value="true"/>
        <set-property property="removeAbandoned"            value="true"/>
        <set-property property="testWhileIdle"              value="true"/>
        <set-property property="validationQuery"            value="SELECT NULL FROM DUAL"/>
    </data-source>
</data-sources>
```

How can I extend it and change it to jndi? like my application as below:

> applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName">
        <value>java:comp/env/jdbc/abcd</value>
    </property> 
</bean>
```

I am using tomcat for development, but the actual environment are IBM websphere 7.0. The connection jndi will provide form the websphere 7.0.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the data-source element is not recommended for use; use DAOs and manage it all through Spring. See the [datasource Struts 1 docs](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.8/faqs/database.html#manager).

(Link is to 1.2 docs, since you don't state what version you're using.)

Comment: I am using struts2, and above “struts-config.xml” is provide by our 3rd party api, and how they the api can connection to the database is already been done by them just using this file. Now is the problem our client want us to change this connection string to jndi, so that they(client) can control it just using the websphere application server 7.0 console.